# Aws Lambda + Django + django-storages + collectstatic inconsistent behaviour

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-zappa

1. I am running aws lambda.
2. It is deployed with zappa.
3. Lambda runs a django project.
4. Django uses django-storages lib to use S3 for storage and serving static files.

I run collectstatic successfully.
I see my admin page with fully loaded js and css.
Next day I come back and see plain html admin page without js and css loaded. I continue navigating through admin page and after some time css and js magically loads. I continue doing some work and css/js again dissapears and admin page becomes plain html again.

Anyone experiencing something similar? Any ideas of why is this happening?

EDIT:

5. Lambda is invoked through API Gateway

Comment: Do you see anything in the console that could provide more insight (Like http codes, correct urls, etc)?

Comment: This is definitely what i tried to look for. Nothing interesting in S3/CW logs. All requests are successful.

Comment: You can try the endpoint yourself. I forgot to mention that it uses API gateway too.
https://wms3fjm0b3.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/admin

Comment: I have noticed one strange behaviour. If I spam hard refresh a lot (ctrl + shift + r) sometimes js/css loads up. I think API gateway might be casheing something.

Comment: Sounds like it's saving the static files to your Lambda's temporary file system. Do you see it uploading to S3 when you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: Yes I do. I even verified if the specified bucket contains all the js/css files and it certainly does.